# Can I make the Windows folder require a password to access it? [Edit/change or add flder and data]

Tags: windows, password, security

Recently, I was thinking that while running wine an application that contains a virus can inject into the windows folder. I don't know if this is possible, but it would be nice to make the Windows folder password protected to change it.

Answer (score 0):

You can download any windows folder lock application that could work with Wine. That's it. Here an [app](http://www.axantum.com/axCrypt/Downloads.html) you can give a try.

Now for your fears of virus and malware in Wine, take a look on those:

- [Do Wine Viruses only work while Wine is running?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562388/do-wine-viruses-only-work-while-wine-is-running)
- [Could Autorun Virus, affect my PC via Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/361781/could-autorun-virus-affect-my-pc-via-wine)